# Google Map check if a route/direction is pass over route store in kml file?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is possible verify if the route generated by user, crossed trough to other route stored in a kml file?

I found in the API Docs:

Class Direction have Ltg Ltd array.

Can I use Google API for compare each point approximation in kml file? or maybe i should do it with a script,  in my server side?

Some one have something similar?

Thanks, developer community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use fusion table:

1. Make your map in google maps with lines or figures and save/export as KML file and download.
2. Login in google docs and crate a new document type: "Table" the wizard shows import file.
3. Import your data: select kml file and upload into the table.
4. The column called "geometry" (by default), store your Lgt Ltd o polylines or polygons.
5. Now you need "query" the data in your table for this you can consult the correct syntax in https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide
6. If you want ask for Lgt & Ltd contains in your the geometry you need

   ```
   SELECT <columns> FROM <tableid> 
   WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('<column with coordinates>',RECTANGLE(LATLNG(<point_lower_x>,
   <point_lower_y>),LATLNG(<point_upper_x>,<point_upper_x>)))
   ```